# Scrape web sites with unique url (python)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am currently working on a project of web scraping but i have difficulties with the url of the web site, because it's not changing when i'm going through the pages.

The website: https://www.centris.ca/fr/triplex~a-vendre~montreal-mercier-hochelaga-maisonneuve?uc=1&view=Thumbnail

My goal is to scrape all the buildings in the two pages.

The only way i can scrape the data is by using the inspect tool and copy the wrapper around all the ads.

This is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv
import string
import glob

#Grab the soup (content)
source = requests.get("https://www.centris.ca/fr/triplex~a-vendre~montreal-mercier-hochelaga-maisonneuve?uc=1&view=Thumbnail")

soup = BeautifulSoup(source.content, 'html.parser')

    #Loop through all the ads on the page
    for ad in soup.find_all('div', {"data-id":"templateThumbnailItem"}):
        if (soup.find('div', {"class":"price"})):

            #Get the address
            address = ad.find('span', {"class":"address"})
            address = address.findChild().text
            address = address.strip()


            #Get the district
            district = ad.find('span', {"class":"address"})
            district = district.findChildren()[1].text
            district = district.strip()


            #Get the type
            typeBuilding = ad.find('span', {"class":"category"}).text
            typeBuilding = typeBuilding.strip()
            typeBuilding = typeBuilding[0:7].strip()


            #Get the Price
            price = ad.find('span', {"itemprop":"price"}).text
            price = price.replace('$','')
            price = price.replace(u'\xa0','')
            price = int(str(price))

            cnt = cnt + 1


            print(f'Adresse: {address}, Quartier: {district}, Type: {typeBuilding}, Prix: {price}$')
```

Thank you for helping!

Comment: I’m not sure I understand, what is your question?

Comment: I want to know how to scrape the two pages on the website. The difficulty is that the url doesn't change when I click on the second page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        r = req.get(
            "https://www.centris.ca/fr/triplex~a-vendre~montreal-mercier-hochelaga-maisonneuve?uc=1&view=Thumbnail")
        with open("data.csv", 'w', newline="", encoding="UTF-8") as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow(["Address", "Quartier", "Type", "Price"])
            for num in range(0, 40, 20):
                data = {'startPosition': num}
                r = req.post(url, json=data).json()
                html = r["d"]["Result"]["html"]
                soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
                prices = [format(int(price.get("content")), ',d') for price in soup.findAll(
                    "span", itemprop="price")]
                block = soup.findAll("div", class_="location-container")
                ty = [ty.div.get_text(strip=True) for ty in block]
                add = [add.select_one(
                    "span.address div").text for add in block]
                quartier = [quar.select_one(
                    "span.address div:nth-child(2)").text for quar in block]
                final = zip(add, quartier, ty, prices)
                writer.writerows(final)


main("https://www.centris.ca/Mvc/Property/GetInscriptions")
```

Output: [View Online](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yeAaQ6Eyb-Fhomt66FyhhsnFpd50NThz_7ntX1Emy8o/edit?usp=sharing)

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated!